# Can I have only event without delegate?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events, delegates

I have a player with the event "shoot". If the player shoots a bullet I manually trigger the event. A different GameObject has a script where if listener and if event triggered, listener perform specific method. I'm new to events. I really don't need delegate, only event. I'm teaching myself programming from internet but everywhere is how to use event only with delegate.

Can I have only event without delegate and if yes how to declare event like this?

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "I really don't need delegate"? The *type* of an event has to be a delegate, so it's not really clear what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you technically *can* have events without a delegate as described in the [answers here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/216893be-27b2-49a8-b563-3be1cd875049/can-events-exist-without-delegates?forum=clr).

However, delegates are used to pass information from where the event was raised. Without it, the program doesn't know where the event was called from and what information to pass.

This is a [good introduction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/event) and there are lots of examples on SO to help with niche cases. For now, if you're self-learning programming, I'd recommend you learn the pattern and get it working before worrying about why the delegate and event always come as a pair.

```
public delegate void ShootEventHandler(object sender, ShootEventArgs e);
public class ShootEventArgs
{
    public ShootEventArgs(string s) { Text = s; }
    public String Text {get; private set;} // readonly
}
```

It's commmon to pass `this` in sender and then new up the delegate you created. Where you want to call shoot, you'd have something like this.

```
var handler = this.Shoot; // Get the event you want to fire
handler?.Invoke(this, new ShootEventArgs("Bang")); // tell eveything interested "Bang"
```

GameObjects interested in the shoot event can subscribe to the information like so:

```
this.Player.Shoot += this.ShootHandler;
public void ShootHandler(object sender, ShootEventArgs e) // common to use e for event args
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Text); // print "Bang"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

An event is a delegate with safety constraint.

- You can only call an event from the class that holds it.
- You can only register/unregister to an event from outside the class (only +=/-=)
- You cannot pass an event as parameter
- You can only wipe clean an event from the class that holds it (eventName = null)

Off topic : UnityEvent is not a real event, it is a class that contain a list of delegate (Action).

When you call an event (or a delegate), you should always check for nullity as you never know if the reference points to an object. You do not need this with UnityEvent since as I mentioned it is not real event and then if the collection is empty nothing happens.

```
public delegate void MyDel();
// The two following behaves the same
public MyDel myDel;
public Action myAction;

public event Action myEvent;

void Start(){
     if(myAction != null){ myAction(); }
     if(myEvent != null) { myEvent(); }
     if(myEvent != null) { myEvent.Invoke(); }
}
```

those are same things, but the choice of whether one or the other is based on what you want to do.

Consider the following in another class:

```
void Start(){
    refToClass.myAction = MyMethod;
    refToClass.myEvent += MyMethod;
}
void MyMethod(){}
```

First case will remove all methods attached to the delegate and MyMethod is then the only one left to listen.
The event will not allow that, only  +=/-= are allowed so you can only remove/add a method without affecting the others.

Answer (score 2):

A *delegate* basically describes a function type. An *event* is a hook where registered functions matching a given function type are called when the event occurs.

Putting together these two simplified definitions, a delegate is also a descriptor for an event, therefore you cannot have an event without a related delegate.

Anyway, you are not forced to declare a new delegate for every event you declare. Instead, you can use any of the preexisting delegates such as [`EventHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.eventhandler), [`EventHandler<TEventArgs>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.eventhandler-1) or even any of the [`Action`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action) overloads, choosing in the one that fits you best in each case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can declare an event without declaring a delegate by using Action. Action is in the System namespace. So make sure you add "using System;" statement at the top of your code file.

```
//No parameter
delegate void _delegate1(); 
static event _delegate1 _event1;

//Parameterized
delegate void _delegate2(bool flag);
static event _delegate2 _event2;
```

this is equivalent to

```
static event Action _event1;
static event Action<bool> _event2;
```